# Can the posterior mean always be expressed as a weighted sum of the maximum likelihood estimate and the prior mean?

Tags: probability, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, prior, posterior

See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376990/show-posterior-mean-can-be-written-as-a-weighted-average-of-the-prior-mean-and-m) question.
Is this always true? Can the posterior mean always be expressed as a weighted sum of the maximum likelihood estimate and the prior mean (after choosing some appropriate prior)?

Answer (score 5):

In (parameter) dimension one, since $$\mathbb E[\theta | x_1,\ldots,x_n]=
\dfrac{\mathbb E[\theta | x_1,\ldots,x_n]}{\hat{\theta}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+\mathbb E[\theta]}\hat{\theta}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+\dfrac{\mathbb E[\theta | x_1,\ldots,x_n]}{\hat{\theta}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+\mathbb E[\theta]}\mathbb E[\theta]$$
it is formally always possible.

To quote from an [earlier answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/486888/7224) of mine to an [earlier question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/486602/7224),

> when $\theta$ is of dimension one, it is always possible to write
> $$\mathbb E[\theta|\mathbf x] = w(\mathbf x) \mathbb E[\theta] + (1-w(\mathbf x)) \hat\theta(\mathbf x)$$
> by solving in $w(x)$ but (i) there is no reason for $0\le w(x)\le 1$
> and (ii) this representation does not extend to larger dimensions as
> $w(\mathbf x)$ will vary for each component.

[image]

For exponential families, it is a generic property (see [Diaconis and Ylvisaker, 1979](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176344611), and my [undergrad course slide](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ceremade.dauphine.fr%2F%7Exian%2FMD3%2Festima.pdf&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGvKacqHVCZnRZpNTvdqBU43aX5kw) above) that the posterior expectation of the mean of the natural statistic is a convex combination of the prior expectation and the maximum likelihood estimate. (The [question you refer to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376990/show-posterior-mean-can-be-written-as-a-weighted-average-of-the-prior-mean-and-m) is a special case.) Note however that this does not transfer to the posterior mean of any transform $\phi(\theta)$ of the mean parameter $\nabla\psi(\theta)$ since the expectation of the transform is not the transform of the expectation ([another slide](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ceremade.dauphine.fr%2F%7Exian%2FMD3%2Festima.pdf&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGvKacqHVCZnRZpNTvdqBU43aX5kw) of my undergrad course!), while the maximum likelihood estimate of the transform is the transform of the maximum likelihood estimate.

[Diaconis and Ylvisaker, 1979](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176344611) actually show a reciprocal to the above result, namely that if the posterior expectation of $\nabla\psi(\theta)$ is linear in the natural sufficient statistic with *fixed weights* then the prior is necessarily conjugate:

[image]

In a general setting there is no reason for the posterior mean to be located "between" the prior mean and the maximum likelihood. Consider a situation where

1. the likelihood is multimodal, with the highest mode (i.e., the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat\theta_1$) being very narrow and with another local mode $\hat\theta_2$ being quite widespread
2. the prior is multimodal, with the prior mean being located on a modal region where the likelihood is essentially zero, and a second modal region $A_2$ covering the second likelihood mode $\hat\theta_2$

the posterior mean could then be located near $\hat\theta_2$, away from both the prior mean and the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat\theta_1$.

Comment: Here, do the coefficients of $\theta_{MLE}$ and $\theta_{prior}$ sum up to $1$?

Comment: @gunes: they do not, indeed, but my point with this remark is to signify that the question is too vague. (Formally, the notion of a weighted sum does not impose the weights to sum up to one.)